# Getting the length of data in a PScustomobject while querying AD

Tags: powershell, sorting, string-length, pscustomobject

I am trying to get a pscustomobject to sort by Canonicalname length, but in order to do this I need the length of each CanonicalName within the PScustomobject.

The Canonicalnamelen is where the length needs to be stored and sorted.
The reason I need to do this is so I can delete OU's within AD that are longer before the lower OU's(But that is not the issue) - i.e. (delete OU /computers/location/IT/test before deleting /computers/location/IT)

So as a result of sorting the list by Canonical Length the canon locations would show like this:
/computers/location/IT/test
/computers/location/IT

The lesser length being always below.

Hope I have explained OK.

My code is as below:

```
$SourceOU = "OU=Computers,DC=domain,DC=my,DC=my"
##Load up OU's into variable
$OUszero = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Properties CanonicalName, DistinguishedName, Description  -Filter *  -SearchBase $SourceOU | Sort-Object CanonicalName |
ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name          = Split-Path $_.CanonicalName -Leaf
        ###I need the length of each object string from CanonicalName and display below in 
        ##CanonicalNamelen. 
        CanonicalName = $_.CanonicalName    
        DistinguishedName  = $_.DistinguishedName
        #UserCount     = @(Get-AdUser -Filter * -SearchBase $_.DistinguishedName -SearchScope Subtree).Count
        ComputerCount = @(Get-AdComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $_.DistinguishedName -SearchScope Subtree).Count
        ###Here is where I need the length of the object to appear.  
        ##But it just gives a count of canonical names 
        CanonicalNamelen = ($OUszero.Canonicalname.Length)  
       
    }
} | Where-Object ComputerCount -EQ 0

$OUszero | FT
```

Comment: Replace `($OUszero.Canonicalname.Length)` with `($_.Canonicalname.Length)` to use your current ou in the foreach (as you did for others).
By the way, you can use expression in sort-object and avoid creating the CanonicalNamelen property like: 
`| Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = { $_.CanonicalName.length }}`

Comment: And finally, you can check the documentation for the cmdlet Remove-ADOrganizationalUnit, it contains a parameter `-recurse` which takes care of deleting the child object if OU is not  empty which also avoid this triage

Comment: This has answered my query.